# What happens when calling this non-existent constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

When compiling this c++ code, I get an error on the last line.

```
#include <iostream>

class TestClass {

public:
    TestClass(int val) 
        : value(val)
    {
    }

    int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

private:
    int value;

};

int main()
{
    TestClass b();
    std::cout << b.getValue() << std::endl;     
}
```

The compiler (gcc on Ubuntu 14.04) complains:

```
error: "request for member ‘getValue’ in ‘b’, which is of non-class type ‘TestClass()’"
```

Now my question is: What exactly does `b` contain? The compiler doesn't complain about `TestClass b()`.

Comment: It is a function declaration. Plenty of duplicates out there.

Comment: You're right. Funny that I can make a function declaration within main(), but not a function definition.

Answer (score 3):

You have a vexing parse with:

```
TestClass b(); // This is a declaration of function b which return TestClass.
```

If you have default constructor, use:

```
TestClass b;
```

or

```
TestClass b{};
```

But as you only have constructor with int parameter do

```
TestClass b(42);
```

or

```
TestClass b{42};
```